# MATLAB map initialisation from a structure array

Tags: matlab, data-structures, dictionary, initialization

My aim is to initialise a Map object with a double for key and structure for value.

I have a structure array similar to this:

```
s(1) = [1,2,3];
s(1) = 'str';
s(2) = [4,5,6];
s(2) = 'str2';
s(3) = [7,8,9];
s(3) = 'str3';
```

Then I want to create a map object like:

```
awesome = container.Map(1:3, s);
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error using containers.Map
Specified value type does not match the type expected for
this container.
```

But it works if I do:

```
awesome = container.Map(1:3, {s1, s2, s3});
```

Why does this happen and how can I make it work while keeping structure as the value type?

Comment: You need to be more clear about exactly how your structure is created

Comment: Your structure set-up doesn't make sense.  Did you miss out some field names?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your structure set-up code was intended to be something like:

```
s(1).Numbers = [1,2,3];
s(1).String = 'str';
s(2).Numbers = [4,5,6];
s(2).String = 'str2';
s(3).Numbers = [7,8,9];
s(3).String = 'str3';
```

you can make a map from the structure array with:

```
theMap = containers.Map( 1:3, arrayfun(@(x) ({x}), s))
```