# When should you use map containers in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Using `Maps` like in the example on MathWorks (see below) seem useful on first sight. But on second thought, they're a container structure, just as Matlab's `struct` variable types. I'm new to `Maps` and missing the advantage of when to use them as opposed to `structs` - to break the question down into some measurable parameters: In what some use-cases is using `Maps` vs `structs` faster and uses less lines of code?

from MathWorks docs, example:

```
months = {'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr'};
rainfall = [327.2 368.2 197.6 178.4];
M = containers.Map(months,rainfall)
```

vs something similar with structs

```
months = {'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr'};
rainfall = [327.2 368.2 197.6 178.4];
for ind=1:numel(months)
  s.(months{ind})=rainfall(ind);
end
```

Comment: This (interesting) question seems to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34767016/2586922). Is it?

Comment: That second answer there has good info on differences. This Q asks for use cases where `Map` is better. I think the answer would be in any case where the difference with `struct` is relevant.

Comment: indeed absolute duplicate, I missed it, please close, thanks for being kind about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A container map is more or less an struct with a customized indexing. You can use them, when you prefer referring to an entry by a certain `char` for instance rather than an index. Let's say you want to recall the value of the rainfall for march.

```
%Declaration map, as you wrote

months = {'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr'};
rainfall = [327.2 368.2 197.6 178.4];
M = containers.Map(months,rainfall);

M('Mar') % 197.6
```

As you see, you not just save a variable, but the reference (as a char, not in the typical way...) as well. For large amounts of data you shouldn'd use maps. Hence I'd recommend you to use maps when you specifically need `char` references and structs for the rest.

> the map is (...) a dictionary, a mapping x --> y without any restrictions on x and y. A struct is a data structure, a way to save data in a logical way. - *@hbaderts*

Just to remind, if you can use a vector instead of a struct, definitely do so!

You will find other valuable informations about maps at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767016/the-difference-between-a-container-map-and-a-struct-in-matlab).

Comment: You can create a `stuct` that does exactly the same as the map in this answer. You'd index as `M.('Mar')`. A `struct` in MATLAB is also dictionary. The difference is that keys in a `struct` must be valid variable names, whereas keys in a `Map` can be anything, including numeric arrays. Other differences are less important, IMO. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38933556/7328782) to the question you linked discusses the differences correctly.

Comment: I agree with Cris on this... thanks for the effort though