# Store values from a MATLAB for loop similar to a Python dictionary

Tags: matlab, dictionary, for-loop

I am looping through files (using for loop) and getting two values from each loop - name and tag. What is the best way to store these values, if I later want to access tags using names?

1. Is there anything similar to python dictionary: `{'name1': tag1, 'name2': tag2, .... 'nameN': tagN}`
2. Or should it be stored in a table with two columns - name and tag

Thanks

Comment: The closest thing to dictionaries in MATLAB, I can think of, are [Map Containers](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html).

Comment: Also: Does this answer your question? [Create a MATLAB dictionary like in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804013/create-a-matlab-dictionary-like-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want `containers.Map`

You can store the name/value pairs in a cell array, then stick these into a map for later reference

```
% Create loop data
N = 10;
data = cell(N,2);
for ii = 1:N 
    data{ii,1} = sprintf( 'Name%.0f', ii );
    data{ii,2} = sprintf( 'Tag%.0f', ii );
end
% Create map
m = containers.Map( data(:,1), data(:,2) );
```

You can then evaluate this in two ways

```
% For a single value
m( 'Name1' ) % = 'Tag1';
% For one or more values
m.values( {'Name1','Name2'} ) % = {'Tag1','Tag2'};
```

The only real advantage of using a map here is syntax unless your data especially lends itself to being in this structure. It isn't much harder to just use logical indexing once you have the `data` array

```
data( ismember(data(:,1), 'Name1'), 2 ) % = {'Tag1'}
```

You could even make an anonymous function as shorthand for this operation (after defining `data`), which saves requiring the `.values` syntax used by maps

```
f = @(str) data( ismember( data(:,1), str ), 2 );
f( 'Name1' ) % = {'Tag1'}
f( {'Name1','Name2'} ) % = {'Tag1','Tag2'}
```

> Note that the `ismember` approach will not throw an error if your `'NameX'` is not found, whereas the map will throw an error if the key doesn't exist.